# How can I know whether a binary file is an executable or a library?

Tags: file-types

I have a binary file, but how can I know the file type- lib or exe?
By opening it with notepad++, it shows:

> ELF and a lot of random symbols.

Comment: Why is this tagged c?

Comment: the binary file is generated from c files

Comment: If you have the source, shouldn't you know what you are building from it? I don't think it will affect the answer, but I'm curious to know the scenario.

Comment: The bin is from others, all I know is that it is built from c.

Answer (score 4):

This is an ELF binary, a binary format used on Unix based systems.

Open the file in a Hex editor. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) At offset 0x10 you should find 2 bytes for the e_type field. You should see a value of 1, 2, 3, or 4.

1 = relocatable
2 = executable
3 = shared
4 = core

You can also look into using [readelf](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) to extract this information for you. You should be able to run it in Cygwin (though I haven't tried it personally).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.     Since we also know it is ELF file, then we can judge the exact type based on value of 0x10.  Then what if it is not an ELF file, how to know whether it is a lib file.

Comment: I think you need to identify the binary format (PE, ELF, Mach-o, or something else) before you can identify if it is a library or an executable. I don't know of a single method that will work for all of them. Maybe some high end hex editors can do it, but I don't know of any free tools that can.